# Eclipse editor rightside-bar in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, user-interface

When programming in Eclipse I use small vertical bar on the right side of the editor.
When I get errors, they are displayed as red boxes there so I can see if file contains errors and quickly jump to that place.
Also warnings and other stuff is displayed there.

Question: is there something similar for Visual Studio (2008)?
It sounds strange that nobody created such useful addon for VS, but I haven't found anything in google regarding my question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything in plain VS but with CodeRush from DevExpress or Resharper from Jetbrains this feature is delivered as part of those plusings.

**Edit:** They do not only show errors but code issues too, meaning code analysis with rules in a way similar to FX Cop.

-sa

Comment: Thank you! Just want to add that CodeRush seems to not contain this, but Reshaper does contain, and they call it "on-the-fly error detection". 
I also tried to google for "marker bar", but with no luck..

Comment: DevExpress names this code issues. I know it because I own the devexpress line of IDE tools products ;)